# How to find relative-latest child record for a multi-level parent-child table relationship

Tags: sql

We have a multi-level table relationship similar to the following:

[image: table-relationship]

We're trying to find the contract.contract_id for each user in the user_hist table where the last_changed_date on each of employer_contract_hist, contract_hist, and contract is the "latest" relative to the user_hist.audit_date.

Is there a better way to do this than something like the following query? Note: the following SQL might not even work. I'm still trying to work my head around the problem.

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    c.contract_id
FROM 
    user_hist u,
    employer_contract_hist ech,
    contract_hist ch,
    contract c
WHERE u.employer_id = ech.employer_id_fk
AND ech.last_changed_date = (select max(ech2.last_changed_date)
                            from employer_contract_hist ech2
                            where ech2.last_changed_date < u.audit_date
                            and ech2.employer_id_fk = ech.employer_id_fk
                            and ech2.contract_hist_fk = ech.contract_hist_fk)
AND ech.contract_hist_fk = ch.contract_hist_id
AND ch.last_changed_date = (select max(ch2.last_changed_date)
                            from contract_hist ch2
                            where ch2.last_changed_date < u.audit_date
                            and ch2.contract_hist_id = ch.contract_hist_id
                            and ch2.contract_id_fk = ch.contract_id_fk)
AND c.contract_id = ch.contract_hist_id
AND c.last_changed_date = (select max(c2.last_changed_date)
                            from contract c2
                            where c2.last_changed_date < u.audit_date
                            and c2.contract_id = c.contract_id)
```

Comment: if you are using MS SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use OVER + PARTITION BY clause https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: We are, and I did consider that, but i'm not sure what exactly i would be selecting over / partitioning by, with regards to the hierarchy.

Comment: I think that you have your "partition" columns in the where of each subselect, excluding the condition: last_changed_date < u.audit_date (which should probably end up on the joins); I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Mind the below code isn't tested, so it's possible you'd have to tweak this a bit to achieve the exact results you want.)

I think you can achieve what you want using the clause `over(partition by)`, and, to further filter the results, put the "<" conditions on joins.

You'd have to benchmark this, but I believe that on large tables the performance should be faster than with "max" subselects.

```
select user_id, contract_id
from(
    select
        u.user_id
        ,c.contract_id
        ,ech.last_changed_date
        ,max(ech.last_changed_date) over(partition by ech.employer_id_fk,ech.contract_hist_fk) as ech_max_last_changed_date
        ,ch.last_changed_date
        ,max(ch.last_changed_date) over(partition by ch.contract_hist_id,ch.contract_id_fk) as ch_max_last_changed_date
        ,c.last_changed_date
        ,max(c.last_changed_date) over(partition by c.contract_id) as c_max_last_changed_date
    from user_hist u
    inner join employer_contract_hist ech 
      on u.employer_id = ech.employer_id_fk and ech.last_changed_date < u.audit_date
    inner join contract_hist ch 
      on ech.contract_hist_fk = ch.contract_hist_id and ch.last_changed_date < u.audit_date
    inner join contract c 
      on c.contract_id = ch.contract_hist_id and c.last_changed_date < u.audit_date
)a
where last_changed_date=ech_max_last_changed_date 
and last_changed_date=ch_max_last_changed_date 
and last_changed_date=c_max_last_changed_date
```

Comment: This gave me enough information to build something that i think works for our case. Thanks!